# Is "malpractice" confined to the medical world?

Tags: word-choice

Could you sue a plumber, an architect or a lawyer for **malpractice** or would you rather have to use a different word such as e.g. "*negligence*"?

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/malpractice) doesn't seem to pose such a restriction but I'm not totally convinced.

Comment: [*Plumber Liability Insurance And Why You Should Have It... **Such careers carry a greater risk of increasingly being accused of malpractice***](http://menifield5.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/plumber-liability-insurance-and-why-you.html) There's nothing wrong with that usage - it's just that *medical* and *legal* malpractice are the two most common types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used literally, *malpractice* could mean doing almost anything in an incorrect fashion, or at least, anything within the scope of one's work.

As a legal matter, malpractice is generally restricted to professional work, such as a doctor, lawyer, or architect, where the practitioner is required to be specially trained at the post-graduate level and licensed by the state.  Plumbers and hair-stylists don't count.

Because a doctor is the professional the average person will consult with most often during his life, *malpractice* unadorned is often taken to mean medical malpractice, but this  is not a legal or linguistic restriction.

Answer (score 1):

The definition Google uses makes it seem clear that malpractice does not have any medical restrictions, even mentioning malpractice in law.

> **Malpractice**
>
> improper, illegal, or negligent professional activity or treatment, especially by a medical practitioner, lawyer, or public official.

The use of "professional" in the description of the word however imposes another potential "restriction" on the word, that is can only be used in cases deemed professional.

For example: Malpractice does not apply to a bad sandwich that your brother makes for you.

Malpractice does apply when a lawyer doesn't defend you, but rather slanders you because he has distaste for you.

Comment: Malpractice applies when a lawyer doesn't represent you *competently*. I don't see how slander or distaste are relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has an entry for [Legal malpractice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_malpractice).

> Legal malpractice is the term for negligence, breach of fiduciary duty, or breach of contract by an attorney that causes harm to his or her client. In order to rise to an actionable level of negligence (an actual breach of a legal duty of care), the injured party must show that the attorney's acts were not merely the result of poor strategy, but that they were the result of errors that no reasonably prudent attorney would make.

Not only can you sue a lawyer for malpractice, but there are law firms that will represent the lawyer being sued. For instance, see this web page to [Find a Local Legal Malpractice lawyer](http://www.lawyers.com/legal-malpractice/find-law-firms-by-location/).

Comment: I wonder how many lawyers who defend other lawyers against legal malpractice are themselves ever sued for malpractice.   I also wonder if lawyers who take the plaintiff's side in such cases ask themselves if such a litigious client is a good idea.